# Как задать расположение данных в таблице?

Tags: python, pandas

Как можно изменить расположение данных в таблице у меня с помощью этой конструкции

```
             df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[1, 2, 3, 14, 21]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5],axis=0)
             df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[2, 3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
             df3 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 9, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)


             result = df1.loc[df1.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
             result2 = df2.loc[df2.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
             result3 = df1.loc[df1.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
             result4 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]


             datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result3]], axis=0)
             datafr.insert(5, " ", "", allow_duplicates=True) 

             datafr1 = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [datafr, result2, result4]], axis=1)
             datafr1.insert(11, " ", "", allow_duplicates=True)

             while True:
                 try:

                     datafr1.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Лист', startrow=2,
                                      startcol=0, header=None, index=False)
                     break  

                 except IOError:
                     QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message','У вас открыт файл "Результат" закройте пожалуйста файл ')
```

сейчас выводит пользователю результат вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужно показать так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка на файлы с данными](https://transfiles.ru/nndlj)

Comment: что перед отсупами мы угадаем по солнцу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas
otstup=pandas.DataFrame(zip(['a1','a2','a3'],['b1','b2','b3']),columns=['a','b'],dtype='string')
#фрейм с данными относительно которого будут отступы
#    a   b
#0  a1  b1
#1  a2  b2
#2  a3  b3

added=pandas.DataFrame(zip(['A1','A2'],['B1','B2']),columns=['a','b'],dtype='string')
#фрейм который добавляется в конец
#    a   b
#0  A1  B1
#1  A2  B2

filled=pandas.DataFrame(zip(*[['$' for i in range(len(otstup.index))] for x in range(len(otstup.columns))]),columns=['a','b'],dtype='string')
#Промежуточный фрейм равный размерами фрейму отступов с залитыми по умолчанию значениями

result=pandas.concat([filled,added],axis=0,ignore_index=1)
#    a   b
#0   $   $
#1   $   $
#2   $   $
#3  A1  B1
#4  A2  B2
```

Предположительное решение: создаём фрейм с значениями по умолчанию затем соеденяем его с целевым

Comment: Подскажите как можно задать в этой конструкции otstup=pandas.DataFrame(zip([здесь количество отступов не строками а числом?]),columns=['a'],dtype='string')

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ Вместо `filled=pandas.DataFrame(zip(*[['$' for i in range(len(otstup.index))] for x in range(len(otstup.columns))]),columns=['a','b'],dtype='string')` следует написать `filled=pandas.DataFrame(zip(*[['$' for i in range(СТРОК_ДЛЯ_ОТСТУПА)] for x in range(КОЛИЧЕСТВО_СТОЛБЦОВ)]),columns=['a','b'],dtype='string')`